# VK Api likes.add

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте, необходимо в приложении добавить возможность лайкнуть запись, в документации написано, что необходимо вызвать `likes.add()`. Но класс `VKApi` не обладает таким методом. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следующий метод ставит лайк:

```
public static String setLike(String type, String owner_id, int item_id ) {
    final String[] res = {""};
    VKRequest request = new VKRequest("likes.add", VKParameters.from("type", type, "owner_id", owner_id, "item_id", item_id));
    request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");
                res[0] = jsonObject.getString("likes");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return res[0];
}
```

Запуск метода:

```
setLike("post", "-id_группы_ВК", i);
```

Думаю, входные параметры для метода

> String type, String owner_id, int item_id

вы замените сами.